# WooCommerce: How to sell products to selected countries only?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to configure WooCommerce in a way that product A can only be sold to country C and product B only to country D? I know that you can set a list of "allowed" countries but this is then valid for all products. So can you define an allowed contry list for every product individually?

Background: Due to the EU VAT law and the Kleinunternehmerregelung I have to include VAT when shipping to EU countries but I don't need to include VAT when shipping to other countries worldwide. But unfortunately it is very difficult to get this working in woocommerce. One of the ideas was to have two separate products, one EU-product (taxable = yes) and one world-product (taxable = no) and let the EU product sell to EU countries only and the world product to countries except EU. If you have other ideas they are welcome, too.

Comment: in this link there is the video tutorial for do it https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-guided-tour-videos/

Comment: WooCommerce will do exactly what you want tax-wise, without the workaround you are trying.  See this excellent article: https://marketpress.com/2014/woocommerce-tax-classes/ - basically, you can set different tax rates for different countries.

Comment: Thanks cale_b. I am actually using the marketpress plugins and they can setup the EU VAT correctly. Unfortunately the "Kleinunternehmerregelung" is not supported. This is an exception for small businesses which do not need to charge VAT if the sales volume is low. What I could do is set the VAT to 0% for non EU countries. But AFAIK it is unfortunately not allowed to use a mark like "includes 0% VAT".